# build file for native scripts of viveMediaPlayer

Tags: unity-game-engine, decoder, windows-media-player, htc-vive

Anyone has a build file (or make file) for native c++ scripts of the ViveMediaDecoder (a Mediaplayer in Unity for Windows platform)

https://github.com/ViveSoftware/ViveMediaDecoder